# Change Projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am a little bit lost here.

working in QGis 2.8, OS X 10.10.

I have a polygon shp in the CRS

`EPSG: 21781, CH1903 / LV03`

and a point file in

`EPSG: 4326, WGS84`

How would I work with these Layers if I i.e. want to perform a `Select by Location`?
Simpy by "Right Click on the Layer -> Properities -> Change CRS to one of the two CRS" its not done... When displaying them then the one I tried to reproject gehts put in the middle of nowhere...

Some theory on that would also be nice... It seems I am missing some knowledge here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to transform the vector layer with a right click on it > "Save as..."

[image]

You will save a new vector layer (for example "points_21781.shp"). Change the CRS in your 21781, CH1903 / LV03. The new vector layer will have the right CRS.

Comment: I could swear I tried that before! It works, thanks!